# Скрипт на локалхосте работает, а на удаленном серваке - нет

Tags: php

Народ! помогите! у меня header(Location:) не работает((( На локал хосте все прет а на серве нет!
вот скрипт:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['pass'])) {
  $max = $_GET['max'];
  $md5 = $_GET['pass'];
  echo $md5;
  $query = fopen('password.txt', "w");
  $query2 = fwrite($query, $md5);
  fclose($query);
  header("Request-URI: example.php?max=$max");
  header("Content-Location: example.php?max=$max");
  header("Location: example.php?max=$max"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: попробуйте закомментировать строку с `echo $md5` и заодно проверить права на запись в файл `password.txt`

Comment: не не помогло...

Comment: обычно когда проблема не совсем очевидна, то я дебажу код полностью его закомментировав. Потом начинаю построчно убирать комментарии, до тех пор пока ошибка не появится. Так и выясняется проблемное место. Попробуйте закомментировать строки по работе с файлом и выводом echo. Если редирект сработает - то проблема в работе с файлом.

Comment: Обычно, когда возникает проблема — смотрят сообщение об ошибке. А т.н. shotgun debugging — последнее дело, когда или голова не варит, или в отладчике слишком сложная картина.

Comment: Почему на локалхосте все работает?!

Comment: Потому что работоспособность зависит от конфигурации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Перед заголовком header() идет вывод текста echo. Сначало должны быть заголовки, а затем вывод текста. Если это страница для перенаправления echo тут не нужен.
2. Куда столько перенаправлений? header("Location: example.php?max=$max"); вполне достаточно будет.
3. Здесть пассивная xss, нужно фильтровать GET запросы, если они выводятся в браузер

   $md5 = $_GET['pass'];

   echo $md5;

header() - это заголовки отправляемые сервером перед документом
echo - это вывод текста самого документа

Выглядит все примерно так:
1. Браузер отправляет запрос например к http://ya.ru
2. Сервер отвечает браузеру так:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 18:06:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Content-Length: 4999
Expires: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 18:06:44 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 18:06:44 GMT
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP ADM DEV PSD IVDo OUR IND STP PHY PRE NAV UNI"
Set-Cookie: yandexuid=9807487461353866804; Expires=Wed, 23-Nov-2022 18:06:43 GMT; Domain=.ya.ru; Path=/
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XRDS-Location: http://openid.yandex.ru/server_xrds/

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
```

Как тут видно сначало сервер отправил заголовки, которые не видно в браузере, но браузер их обрабатывает (HTTP/1.1 200 Ok - получает статус ОК, Server: nginx - имя сервера, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 - тип документа и его кодировку и тд. ),  а затем после пустой строки уже идет сам документ. А в данном случаи заголовки и текст страницы перемешался, что и привело к ошибке.

Comment: вы так и не дали точного ответа... это страница не только для перенаправления и все равно не помогло...

Comment: думаю сейчас понятно